# How can I see all notes of a Tumblr post from Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, tumblr

Say I look at the following Tumblr post: [http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/post/40692813…](http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/post/40692813320)

It (currently) has 292 notes.

I'd like to get **all** the above notes using a Python script (e.g., via urllib2, BeautifulSoup, simplejson, or tumblr Api).
Some extensive Googling did not produce any items relating to notes' extraction in Tumblr.

*Can anyone point me in the right direction on which tool will enable me to do that?*

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately looks like the Tumblr API  has some limitations (lacks of meta information about Reblogs, notes limited by 50), so you can't get all the notes.

It is also forbidden to do page scraping according to the [Terms of Service](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/terms_of_service).

> "You may not do any of the following while accessing or using the Services: (...) scrape the Services, and particularly scrape Content (as defined below) from the Services, without Tumblr's express prior written consent;"

Source:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tumblr-api/ktfMIdJCOmc

Comment: `as defined below` Where is the definition of the term, though? I can't find it...

Answer (score 5):

Without JS you get separate pages that only contain the notes. For the mentioned blog post the first page would be:

> http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/notes/40692813320/4Y70Zzacy

Following pages are linked at the bottom, e.g.:

- http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/notes/40692813320/4Y70Zzacy?from_c=1358403506
- http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/notes/40692813320/4Y70Zzacy?from_c=1358383221
- http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/notes/40692813320/4Y70Zzacy?from_c=1358377013
- …

(See [my answer on how to find the next URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048088/1591669) in `a`’s `onclick` attribute.)

Now you could use various tools to download/parse the data.

The following wget command should download all notes pages for that post:

```
wget --recursive --domains=ronbarak.tumblr.com --include-directories=notes http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/notes/40692813320/4Y70Zzacy
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Fabio implies, it is better to use the API.

If for whatever reasons you cannot, then the tools you will use will depend on what you want to do with the data in the posts.

- for a data dump: urllib will return a string of the page you want
- looking for a specific section in the html: lxml is pretty good
- looking for something in unruly html: definitely beautifulsoup
- looking for a specific item in a section: beautifulsoup, lxml, text parsing is what you need.
- need to put the data in a database/file: use scrapy

Tumblr url scheme is simple: url/scheme/1, url/scheme/2, url/scheme/3, etc... until you get to the end of the posts and the servers just does not return any data anymore.

So if you are going to brute force your way to scraping, you can easily tell your script to dump all the data on your hard drive until, say the contents tag, is empty.

One last word of advice, please remember to put a small sleep(1000) in your script, because you could put some stress on Tumblr servers.

Comment: Thanks Lynx-Lab.
All I want to do is get all the notes from one of my popular posts, so I could create a dgraph of all the people who reblogged it (and wh reblogged from whom).
I don't think the above falls in the scrapping category, but I'm not sure how to go about getting **all** the notes.

Comment: You are welcome User1850727. I called it scraping because as long as you are not using tumblr api, you will need to get the contents then parse it. You can use urllib for getting **all** the data then use any of the above to pick your choose. Please keep in mind @Fabio's comment about the ToS.

Answer (score 0):

**[how to load all notes on tumblr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035018/how-to-load-all-notes-on-tumblr)** also covers the topic, but unor's response (above) does it very well.