# python - tumblr - notes - wget or other solution

Tags: python, selenium, wget, tumblr, scrape

I want to download all the notes in a given tumblr post.

This post for example  http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/notes/40692813320/4Y70Zzacy?

After some research in google and on this site I decided on this method - a wget command via python and then processing in python.

UPDATE: Sorry i didnt state before. The code excutes but it only downloads the first page of notes. It doesn't dig any deeper.

```
import os

os.system("wget --recursive --domains=ronbarak.tumblr.com --include-directories=notes http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/notes/40692813320/4Y70Zzacy?")
```

Could someone point out what I need to change in my wget variables or if it will never work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see all notes of a Tumblr post from Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415592/how-can-i-see-all-notes-of-a-tumblr-post-from-python)

Comment: No its different. Its in some ways an extension of that. I read that and am now stuck with getting what I want from wget.