# how to load all notes on tumblr?

Tags: python, tumblr

i made a giveaway but im having a problem to view the notes. there is no "load more notes" at the bottom. other posts are okay, but i'm not sure why my giveaway post (ONLY THAT POST) won't load all the notes.

i googled and found this --> [How can I see all notes of a Tumblr post from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415592/how-can-i-see-all-notes-of-a-tumblr-post-from-python)

one of the answers for the question made a new page with only the notes. (the one by user unor). i think the user used python or something but im not sure what is that and i tried changing my url to the one mentioned in the answer but nothing works. :( there's even wget command could download all notes pages for that post.

can someone help me? this is my post's url --> http://uri-hyukkie.tumblr.com/post/64967405021

thank you so so soooo much!

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. It should be your own try.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil  thank you for responding! but what code? would you mind helping me? please?

Comment: I don't think I can help, sorry. Try contacting tumblr itself.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil well according to some ppl, tumblr messed up the notes bec holding a giveaway using notes is against their policy. so i really need to find another way to view the notes. or else i cant choose a winner. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your post](http://uri-hyukkie.tumblr.com/post/64967405021) already shows all notes (EDIT: but Tumblr probably blocked/deleted all the other ones).

The oldest note is always your own, so if you can see it, there are no other notes pages:

> uri-hyukkie posted this

If you get more likes/reblogs, you will eventually reach the threshold. Only then you’ll see the "load more notes" link resp. the note pagination.

---

> one of the answers for the question made a new page with only the notes. (the one by user unor). i think the user used python or something but im not sure what is that and i tried changing my url to the one mentioned in the answer but nothing works. :( there's even wget command could download all notes pages for that post.

[I didn’t use Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428010/1591669) or any other programming language. Simply deactivate JavaScript in your browser, then you’ll get the static notes page links. But, as I explained above, you’ll only see these if you have *more* notes.

---

I think I found them:

- http://uri-hyukkie.tumblr.com/notes/64967405021/2nsoCKZ8N?from_c=1382900003
- http://uri-hyukkie.tumblr.com/notes/64967405021/2nsoCKZ8N?from_c=1382759799
- http://uri-hyukkie.tumblr.com/notes/64967405021/2nsoCKZ8N?from_c=1382645074
- …

For me it doesn’t display the static link, but you can get the next URL by looking at the source code: the `onclick` attribute of the `a` element contains

> […] tumblrReq.open('GET','/notes/64967405021/2nsoCKZ8N?from_c=1382486492',true); […]

The `/notes/64967405021/2nsoCKZ8N?from_c=1382486492` part is the URL path of the next page of notes.

Howto:

1. open the source code of a notes page (in Firefox with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>)
2. search for `/notes/` (in Firefox with <kbd>Ctrfl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)
3. copy the whole string enclosed in the two `'`, beginning with `/notes/` and ending with a number
4. append this string at your Tumblr domain: `http://uri-hyukkie.tumblr.com` + *paste the string*
5. open this page in your browser; and repeat

Comment: thank you so much for replying! i actually have 2000+ notes but for some reason it only shows like 20+ notes. unlike other posts, this one doesn't have "load more notes" at the bottom. that's the problem. i cant view the full notes without "load more notes". do you know any way to view them? someone used to have the same problem like me and she said it's unfortunate bec tumblr may have found out about the giveaway which is against their policy. :(

Comment: @user3002364: You are right, this post should have more notes, according to Tumblr’s own statistics. So I *guess* that your Notes were removed by Tumblr for violating "Non-Genuine Social Gesture Schemes." of their [community guidelines](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/community).

Comment: nooooooooooo~~~~ so there's no other way to view the notes? isn't there's a function in google that lets you view old blogs and stuffs even when they're deleted. have you heard about that? :O

Comment: @user3002364: It’s only a *guess*, I never saw such a case before. As to your second question, [yes](http://superuser.com/a/669835/151741), you could [view Google’s cache](https://www.google.com/search?q=cache:http://uri-hyukkie.tumblr.com/post/64967405021). But it only shows the newest notes (loading the older ones won’t work because it tries to request them from Tumblr, which are, probably, deleted/blocked there).

Comment: @user3002364: I think I found them … see the edit of my answer.

Comment: thats certainly better than nothing! is it possible to view the caches from any date that i want?

Comment: @user3002364: Not Google’s, no. But did you see my update? The notes seem to be still there on Tumblr, so no need for external caches.

Comment: ohmygoodness god bless you. thank you so much for your help! is there any way i can contact you? (since i dont really understand about the source code thing but i'll try to find out first ^^)

Comment: @user3002364: Glad that it helped. I updated my answer with a short guide. Feel free to accept my answer. For anything else, you should open a new question.