# Getting more than 50 notes with Tumblr API

Tags: api, limit, tumblr

Is there a way to get more than 50 notes per post from Tumblr API.

According to their API, I need to call the `posts` method with the `notes_info` parameter set to True. Here is the doc:

https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

So I end up constructing an API call like (the API key is public, from their docs):

http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/yearinreview.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4&notes_info=true

The blog in question has more that 50 notes per post, but the API only returns the last 50 in the `result['posts']['notes']` list.

Example: http://jsbin.com/noyejikarawi/1/edit

Is there a way to get around this and fetch the full notes list?

Comment: The offset is used for the posts, so with an offset=10 you will skip the first 10 posts and start from post no 11. It does not affect the notes within the post.

Comment: My mistake and I apologise for removing the api key. I don't actually think its possible to get more than 50 via the API. Its possible if you are creating a theme to trigger a function to get the next 50: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#notes

Comment: Confirmed, sadly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415592/how-can-i-see-all-notes-of-a-tumblr-post-from-python