# How do I get notes info from posts with python/tumblr api?

Tags: python, api, tumblr

I am so confused by all these levels of dicts I have to wade through it would be easier imo just to do it by scraping, however I guess it's a good excercise to learn dicts and will be quicker perhaps once I figure it out.

My code is as follows, where the assignment statement for `cposts` returns a 404:

```
import pytumblr

# Authenticate via OAuth
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
)

f = client.followers('blog.tumblr.com')

users = f['users']

names = [b['name'] for b in f['users']]
print names

cposts = client.posts(names[0], 'notes_info=True')

print (cposts)
```

But the python api info says: client.posts('codingjester', **params) # get posts for a blog

and this SO post ([Getting more than 50 notes with Tumblr API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176275/getting-more-than-50-notes-with-tumblr-api)) says you should use notes_info to get the notes. But I don't know how to construct it in python rather than making a url.

I could use a request constructing a url but I figure there is a simpler way using the python/tumblr api I just haven't figured it out, if someone could illuminate please.

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes from around `notes_info=True`? It doesn't seem to me that they should be there.

Comment: Well that might have been it I did get alot of info back removing the quotes. :) Silly me. Have to analyse the data to check that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `notes_info=True`. You should be passing the value `True` to the `notes_info` argument of the `client`'s `posts()` method. Instead, you're actually passing the string `'notes_info=True'` as a positional argument, which is invalid and causes pytumblr to create an invalid URL, which is why you're getting a 404.

Comment: Yes, that got it. Thanks.