# Is there a way to retrieve all notes from a tumblr post?

Tags: python, web-crawler, tumblr

This question has been asked a few times before, but none of the answers have ever actually managed to find a way to do this.

Tumblr has an [API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) that you can use in conjunction with [pytumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr), but this does not retrieve all notes, it only returns about 50.  I tried using the tumblr api, and didn't manage to get more than 50 notes. I tried using wget to crawl the notes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415592/how-can-i-see-all-notes-of-a-tumblr-post-from-python) user suggested, but it did not work.

Comment: You have to create a loop for the total number of notes and iterate over that loop as long as it is less than the total, using an offset that you increment. Each call to the Tumblr API returns metadata this contains the total count